# Express as a single logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Hi I need to express the following and have no clue how to do so.             $$\ln(x+3)-3\ln(x-7)-\ln(x+8)$$

Can someone please help

Comment: Hint:  What are the basic algebraic properties of logarithms?

Comment: What di you know about log laws?

Comment: Welcome to the site. People here don't like to do your homework for you. Please take some hints in the answer below, attempt the problem and put an update into the question or alert the answerer by a comment...

Answer (score 3):

> You'll need to use the following properties of logarithms:

Given $0 < a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$

- $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$
- $m\log(a) = \log(a^m)$

Comment: +1. I like this answer. It gives the asker all the tools she needs to do the work, but avoids spoon-feeding her.